# Octave: print multiple plots shows only one plot

Tags: matlab, octave

This

```matlab
t = [1:100];
plot(t,t.^2,'b')
hold on
plot(t,t,'og','markersize',5.0)
print -depsc 'test'
```

works as expected, the eps generated looks like this:
[image]

However, when I want to change the face colour of the markers, the blue graph dissapears!

```matlab
t = [1:100];
plot(t,t.^2,'b')
hold on
plot(t,t,'og','markersize',5.0,'markerfacecolor','g') % >markerfacecolor<
print -depsc 'test'
```

The eps now is:

[image]

What's the problem?

The figures (windows) show both versions correctly, the problem is the print part.

Answer (score 3):

I added

```
set(gca,"color","none")
```

just before

```
print -depsc 'test';
```

and it works. I don't know what it does but it solved my problem. I found it here:
http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44577#comment6

Comment: The reason why the blue line disappears is a problem with z-depth where it gets hidden by the background. `set(gca,"color","none")` makes the axes background invisible/transparent and thus the blue line visible again. But this should be solved with gl2ps 1.3.9, apparently you are using a old version (you haven't mention the Octave version nor your operating system which is very bad when asking on SO for help with software)